# Collect survey responses via links in email, w/o running afoul of pre-fetching and GET mis-use

Tags: email, http, standards, html-email, email-client

I'd like to send some users an email asking them a question, and I'd like to make it as easy as possible for them to answer. Ideally the question and the answers would be in the email. Each answer would be a link, which when clicked would record their answer.

Of course, that both violates the use of GET (should be a POST), and is at risk of the the link being pre-fetched by their mail server, or their mail client, or their browser.

My question: is there a best practice for doing this? Are there any good work arounds? How big an issue is pre-fetching?

A few thoughts I've had, though I'm not sure they are good ideas..

1. The links could all load the same page w/o recording an answer. A query parameter in the link could specify which answer was clicked. The JS on the loaded page could parse that, and make a POST with that answer. But maybe some pre-fetching services also execute JS?
2. If the links in the email did record the answer, I could implement some logic so that if more than one answer link was loaded (for a specific email/user) then all the responses from that email/user are marked void. Might mean losing a little data, but would remove false data from pre-fetching (assuming that any pre-fetching algorithm would hit more than one link)
3. I could just build it and see what happens, but it seems I'd have to do a lot of detective work to figure out what's actually happening, and I'm sure someone else has already thought about this more than me :)

thanks

tom

Comment: I'm sure this has been discussed before, but I can't find anything relevant. You could make a page that uses JavaScript to POST the values from the query string, as prefetchers generally don't execute JS.

Comment: Yes, you'd think it had been discussed before, but I cant find anything either. Right now the POST from JS option seems best.

Answer (score 0):

Detecting pre-fetchers is trivial. Just use the user-agent header and don't count votes for known pre-fetchers (I don't have a list - it's something you might need to log and then accumulate over time). I haven't seen a pre-fetcher that doesn't self-identify in their user agent. If you want an extra layer of security, then have the page fire off some Javascript, as it's unlikely that sneaky pre-fetchers will be also running Javascript. Or better yet, just have the user enter a captcha on the vote confirmation page.

Comment: If the pre-fetching comes from the browser (as pre-rendering) then it is not trivial to detect: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=86175  A captcha doesnt really wortk given " I'd like to make it as easy as possible for them to answer" :)

Comment: Yup, this is a general problem of click tracking on the web (think of the costs when serving up pay-per-click ads!). The best bet is to just use Javascript on the resulting page.

Comment: In general though, unless you need 100% accurate survey responses, you're going to find that most people read email on their phone where no browser currently prerenders. A greater issue is duplicate responses - since mobile browsers will reload a webpage when low on memory.

Answer (score 0):

Absent other input, I'm documenting the best solution as:

> The links could all load the same page w/o recording an answer. A
>   query parameter in the link could specify which answer was clicked.
>   The JS on the loaded page could parse that, and make a POST with that
>   answer.